# Spark 1.5.2 + Hadoop 2.6.2 spark-submit and pyspark not utilizing all nodes in standalone

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running into an issue when running spark-submit or pyspark in standalone mode, something like this:

```
spark/bin/pyspark --master spark://<SPARK_IP>:<SPARK_PORT>
```

which typically creates a running Spark application in the UI using all nodes (at least, in previous versions).

For some reason, doing this only runs it on the master node, despite the fact that the UI says that all nodes are connected to the master. There are no errors in the logs on the slave nodes. Anyone have any idea what could've went wrong? For reference, my spark-env.sh has the following configuration:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/mnt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=<PUBLIC_DNS>
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=<PRIVATE_DNS>
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_CLASSPATH:/mnt/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*
export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/persistent/hadoop"
export SPARK_TMP_DIR="/mnt/persistent/hadoop"
export SPARK_MASTER_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/persistent/hadoop"
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/persistent/hadoop"
export SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=5g
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/persistent/hadoop"
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=2
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=23g
```

Here is what pops up after trying to start PySpark:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
15/12/24 01:36:38 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.2
15/12/24 01:36:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/12/24 01:36:38 WARN spark.SparkConf: 
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS was detected (set to '-Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/persistent/hadoop').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with conf/spark-defaults.conf to set defaults for an application
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-java-options to set -X options for a driver
 - spark.executor.extraJavaOptions to set -X options for executors
 - SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS to set java options for standalone daemons (master or worker)

15/12/24 01:36:38 WARN spark.SparkConf: Setting 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions' to '-Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/persistent/hadoop' as a work-around.
15/12/24 01:36:38 WARN spark.SparkConf: Setting 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions' to '-Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/persistent/hadoop' as a work-around.
15/12/24 01:36:38 WARN spark.SparkConf: 
SPARK_CLASSPATH was detected (set to ':/mnt/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-class-path to augment the driver classpath
 - spark.executor.extraClassPath to augment the executor classpath

15/12/24 01:36:38 WARN spark.SparkConf: Setting 'spark.executor.extraClassPath' to ':/mnt/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*' as a work-around.
15/12/24 01:36:38 WARN spark.SparkConf: Setting 'spark.driver.extraClassPath' to ':/mnt/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*' as a work-around.
15/12/24 01:36:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ubuntu
15/12/24 01:36:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ubuntu
15/12/24 01:36:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(ubuntu); users with modify permissions: Set(ubuntu)
15/12/24 01:36:39 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/12/24 01:36:39 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@xx.xx.xx.xx:34065]
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 34065.
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /mnt/persistent/hadoop/blockmgr-16d59ac7-dc2d-4cf7-ad52-91ff1035a86d
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2.6 GB
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /mnt/persistent/hadoop/spark-c6ea28f7-13dc-4799-aea7-0638cff35936/httpd-006916ff-7f84-4ad9-8fb5-bce471d73d5a
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:50882
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 50882.
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4040
15/12/24 01:36:40 WARN metrics.MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
15/12/24 01:36:40 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://xx.xx.xx.xx:7077...
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20151224013641-0001
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20151224013641-0001/0 on worker-20151224013503-xx.xx.xx.xx-40801 (xx.xx.xx.xx:40801) with 4 cores
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20151224013641-0001/0 on hostPort xx.xx.xx.xx:40801 with 4 cores, 23.0 GB RAM
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20151224013641-0001/0 is now LOADING
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20151224013641-0001/0 is now RUNNING
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 58297.
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 58297
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager xx.xx.xx.xx:58297 with 2.6 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, xx.xx.xx.xx, 58297)
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/12/24 01:36:41 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.5.2
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015 17:58:13)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
>>> 15/12/24 01:36:44 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@xx.xx.xx.xx:38929/user/Executor#412940208]) with ID 0
15/12/24 01:36:44 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager xx.xx.xx.xx:44977 with 11.9 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, xx.xx.xx.xx, 44977)
```

Thanks in advance,
Jack

Comment: Can you paste the output? Is it running in local mode?

Comment: Just pasted the output. It's effectively running on local mode but I don't tell it to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the master silently ignoring some slaves. It boiled down to the following:

If the application requires some resources for its executor that cannot be fulfilled by some slaves, these slaves get automatically excluded without a warning.

For example, if the application requires an executor with 6 cores and 11g RAM, and a slave only provides 3 cores, then the slave does not get any tasks from this application. If the number of cores is not specified in the application settings, the maximum allowed per slave are used for the application. This does not apply to memory however.